# OpenVPN: I cant ping from remote to local, but local to remote works

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn, ping

I am trying to ping from remote server to my local, but it does not work properly.

I am accessing an Ubuntu 22.04 Server through SSH(10.30.X.X), it works.

When i try to ping from remote 10.30.X.X to my local (OpenVPN says its 10.8.0.9) it does not work, there's no packets transmitted and 100% packet loss:

[image: Image pinging from remote to my local]

But, when i try to ping from my local, to remote, the ping works properly:

[image: Image pinging from local to remote]

I already tried to ping my 192.168.0.101 but does note work either.

Is it possible to be an OpenVPN server issue or misconfiguration? or is it an client issue?

Comment: The 192.168... and 10... addresses are not forwardable -- they are meant to be local.